# Async Await problem when accessing Vuex store in router.js

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuex

I am trying to access Vuex store in router file.
I need to define routes according to store' data.length.
For example, If store.data is empty, I only need Company List route.
And if not, I only need to Signin route.
Actually data is not empty array but It  always logs as empty array, How can I get store's data without this problem (async/await)?
Here is my code.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import store from '@/store';

Vue.use(Router);

let data = [];
async function getData() {
  data = await store.dispatch('auth/fetchCompanyList');
}

getData();

console.log('data', data);
//data is always empty array.

let routes = [];

if (data.length === 0) {
  routes = [
    {
      path: '/company-list',
      name: 'CompanyList',
      component: () => import('../pages/admin/company/List.vue'),
    },
  ];
} else {
  routes = [
    {
      path: '/signin',
      name: 'Signin',
      component: () => import('../pages/signin.vue'),
    },
  ];
}

console.log('Route: ', routes);

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  // base: process.env.BASE_URL + '/ui/',
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data will be empty when you are logging it because it hasn't received the answer from your store method. You can use `.then()` to access the value of the promise. Then you are free to add more routes to your router using the [`addRoutes()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes) function available.

An implementation can look like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import store from '@/store';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    // base: process.env.BASE_URL + '/ui/',
    routes: [],
});

const getData = async () => {
    data = await store.dispatch('auth/fetchCompanyList');
};
const handleData = (data) => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
        router.addRoutes([
            {
                path: '/company-list',
                name: 'CompanyList',
                component: () => import('../pages/admin/company/List.vue'),
            },
        ]);
    }else{
        router.addRoutes([
            {
                path: '/signin',
                name: 'Signin',
                component: () => import('../pages/signin.vue'),
            },
        ])
    }
};

getData().then(handleData);

export default router;
```

Comment: I wrote console.log(router) after getData().then(handleData) row.
And got routes: [], but actually route was added conditionally.
Problem was not related to async await, I am wondering why I was troubling with Vuex and async await side, didn't try to solve the problem in vue router side.

Comment: Yes, because of the nature of async JavaScript, that's why you get `routes: []`. By the time `console.log` is called on  `routes`, it's empty. I'd suggest reading up on *Asynchronous JavaScript*. Here's an article that might help - https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `getData` method is asynchronous (it will return a promise) and you don't wait for the result of that Promise (it's pending). The promise will not be resolved (it will be pending) without a `.then` block or the `await` keyword.

As a result, `handleData` will run with the initial value of `data`, which is an empty array ([]).

Using the `async/await` syntax in this question throughout will prove to be challenging because `await` can only be used in a function scope containing the `async` keyword.

Therefore, I will show how to use a mix of `.then` and `async/await` and how to use just the `.then` syntax.

I am personally not a fan of mixing `.then` and `async/await` for consistency purposes, as they do the same thing. However, I will leave it to you to decide which approach to take.

#### Purely `.then` syntax

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import store from '@/store';

Vue.use(Router);

let data = [];

function getData() {
  return store.dispatch('auth/fetchCompanyList');
}

getData().then((resolvedData) => {
  data = resolvedData

  let routes = [];

  if (data.length === 0) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}); 

const router = new Router({
 ...
});

export default router;
```

#### Mix of `async/await` syntax and `.then` syntax

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import store from '@/store';

Vue.use(Router);

let data = [];

async function getData() {
  let resolvedPromise = await store.dispatch('auth/fetchCompanyList');
  return resolvedPromise;
}

getData().then((resolvedData) => { // the .then returns the resolved promise. I cannot use `async/await` here because the getData method that is called is not within a scope with the async keyword
  data = resolvedData
 // this will resolve into a promise (any method with the 'async' keyword will resolve into a promise(either rejected or resolved))


  let routes = [];

  if (data.length === 0) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }

});

const router = new Router({
 ...
});

export default router;
```